# Create virtual network interface programmatically

Tags: c#, java, networking, interface, virtual

Is it possible to add a virtual network interface with Java or C#. I need to set a bunch of IPs to my computer for a data mining app and I don't have enought NICs (I don't want to buy more yet).

I need full control of virtual cards from the app (create, delete, set IP, maybe redirect traffic).

Comment: Which operating system? This is a very OS dependant question.

Comment: I have no problem changing the operating system. I can use Windows with C# or Java but can also use a GNU/Linux distro with java... even python. What I need is a stable system.

Comment: IPs and NICs aren't in a 1-1 mapping. You can have multiple IP addresses on a single card.

Comment: Yes, with virtual interfaces. That is what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you have a pure Java solution for this.

You have several alternatives.
1. Use a script that will do that for you, writing this solution in perl\shell will be 4-5 lines.
2. You can open a ssh connection to your machine and run the commands from Java.
   I have such utility that uses trilead-ssh2.

To get it using maven you can use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.trilead</groupId>
        <artifactId>trilead-ssh2</artifactId>
        <version>build213-svnkit-1.3-patch</version>
    </dependency>
```

For example, this way you should open a connection:

```
public static Connection newConnectionWithPassword(String host, String username, String passwd) {
    Connection newConn = new Connection(host);
    try {
        newConn.connect(); // Ignoring ConnectionInfo returned value.
        newConn.authenticateWithPassword(username, passwd);
        return newConn;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        newConn.close();
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then to run your command you can :

```
this.session = conn.openSession();
this.session.execCommand(this.cmd);
```

You can use an OS command to create your virtual interfaces from java now.
BTW, 
You can test the results using NetworkInterface.class , that can query a netweork interface on your machine.

Good luck.